# How to crop raster stack layers based on 90 percentile value of every layer

Tags: r, raster, quantile

I have created a raster stack in R:

```
mylist <- list.files(pattern = "\\.img$")
s <- stack(mylist)
```

and calulated 90 percentile of layers:

```
90quantiles <- quantile(s, probs = .90, na.rm=TRUE)
```

now I don't know how to crop areas with pixels having higher values than 90quantiles in every layer or at least to obtain polygons of these areas.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by "crop areas"? Can you provide a reproducible example and your expected output? e.g starting with something like this: `s <- stack(replicate(3, raster(matrix(runif(100), 10))))`.

Comment: solved this way  
`rs2 <- calc(s, fun=function(x){x > 90quantiles})`  
`rs3 <- rs2*1`  
`writeRaster(rs3, filename="test.tif", format="GTiff", bylayer=TRUE)`

Comment: I'd suggest you to follow @jbaums suggestion and post your solution as an answer. Beside that, I think you are using a wrong terminology. You are masking your original layers don't you?

Comment: Yes, I think you're right about terminology......Thank you!